# Working through multiple files one at a time in perl?

Tags: perl, parsing

I have a perl script that opens a txt file, parses it so that the appropriate text is output to a csv file. I have working great now for one file, but I have loads of similar files to work through in the exact same way. I want to be able to just do this automatically so the code will work through file1.txt and parse the text I want to output.csv, then work through file2.txt and append this output to the same output.csv. I have included the relevan bits of my code below, excluding only the code that does the actual parsing within the while loop since I don't need to alter this. The input files are consistently named, e.g. file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt etc. and all reside in the same directory

```
my $mode = "none";
open(my $infile,"<","file1.txt") or die $!;
open (my $outfile,">>","output.csv") or die $!;
while (<$infile>)
{
    chomp; 
    if ($_ =~ /^Section 1/) {
        $mode = "sec1";
    }
    if ($_ =~ /^Section 2/) {
        $mode = "sec2";
    }

    if ($mode =~ "sec1") {
      $_=~ tr/,//d;

      if ($_ =~ /.\%$/){
        print $outfile $_;
        print $outfile "\n";
      }
      else{
        print $outfile $_;  
      }

    }    
}

close $infile;
close $outfile;
```

The output file should resemble this (not this text obviously, I'm just highlighting that it the output must be appended, which I think I have covered by using >> as opposed to >)

```
this is from file 1
this is from file 2
this is from file 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to wrap this in a loop like so:

```
for my $file ( @list_files ) {
    open $in_fh, "<", $file;
    while (my $line = <$in_fh>) {
    # and the rest of your stuff goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *diamond operator* `<>` and the scalar `$ARGV` variable :

```
use strict; use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print "Processing [$_] from $ARGV\n";
}
```

this is the same as

```
use strict; use warnings;

while (<ARGV>) {
    print "Processing [$_] from $ARGV\n";
}
```

if there's something in `@ARGV`.

Comment: You are right! <> seems to be the same as <ARGV>. Later is a little bit more talkative... Thanks for it!

Comment: @TrueY: `<>` is the same as `<ARGV>` while there is something in `@ARGV`, and the same as `<STDIN>` when `@ARGV` is empty.

Comment: @Borodin: Yes. And `<ARGV>` behaves the same if `@ARGV` is empty.

Comment: @TrueY: I had thought `ARGV` was different and didn't default to `STDIN`. Shame there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the necessary files into `@ARGV` as if they had been typed on the command line. Then read from the `ARGV` filehandle.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our @ARGV = do {
    opendir my $dh, '.' or die $!;
    grep /^file\d+\.txt$/, readdir $dh;
};

while ( <ARGV> ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: What about `@ARGV = glob("file*.txt");`?

Comment: @TrueY: I went for the `grep` / `readdir` in case better filtering was required. There's a lot of difference between `file\d+\.txt` and `file.+\.txt`

Comment: U R right! I meant to use glob instead of the open, readdir, closedir combo. If You really need the strict rules then you can use `@ARGV = grep /^file\d+\.txt$/ glob("file*.txt");`.

Comment: @TrueY: Yes, I understood what you meant. What I was trying to say is that your `glob` is equivalent to finding file names that match the regex `file.+\.txt`. With the addition of the `grep` I think your alternative is much more clumsy than a straightforward `opendir`/`readdir`/`grep` so I stick with my original solution.

Comment: @TrueY `open my $dh, '.';` does not work for me with perl 5.24.1 (Strawberry x86) on Windows 8.1 x64 whereas `@ARGV = glob("file*.txt");` does. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Wolf: Wow this is an old one! Yes, I wrote `open` when I meant `opendir`, that's all. I've tidied up my code; it should work for you now. Thank you for pointing this out. Note that the glob will find files with *anything* between `file` and the dot, while the regex will insist that there are decimal digits there.

Comment: Yes, it works as expected (and I indeed prefer this more selective solution). Thanks for fixing.

Comment: Would it be better to remove the `our` before `@ARGV`? I found a lot of documentation that explicitly states that I don't have to declare this variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to open all files given in the command line. There is a special file handle, called `ARGV`.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<ARGV>) {
    print $_;
}
```

Command line:

```
test.pl file*.txt
```

All files will be concatenated.

If you have the file list "inside" the code, you can load them to the `@ARGV` array, then use `<ARGV>`.