# perl + read multiple csv files + manipulate files + provide output_files

Tags: perl, csv

Apologies if this is a bit long winded, bu i really appreciate an answer here as i am having difficulty getting this to work.

Building on from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466984/script-to-get-the-max-from-column-based-on-other-column-values/22467944?noredirect=1#comment34177528_22467944), i have this script that works on a csv file(orig.csv) and provides a csv file that i want(format.csv). What I want is to make this more generic and accept any number of '*.csv' files and provide a 'output_*csv'  for each inputed file. Can anyone help?

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    open my $orig_fh,   '<', 'orig.csv'   or die $!;
    open my $format_fh, '>', 'format.csv' or die $!;

    print $format_fh scalar <$orig_fh>; # Copy header line

    my %data;
    my @labels;

    while (<$orig_fh>) {
      chomp;
      my @fields = split /,/, $_, -1;
      my ($label, $max_val) = @fields[1,12];
      if ( exists $data{$label} ) {
        my $prev_max_val = $data{$label}[12] || 0;
        $data{$label} = \@fields if $max_val and $max_val > $prev_max_val;
      }
      else {
        $data{$label} = \@fields;
        push @labels, $label;
      }
    }

    for my $label (@labels) {
      print $format_fh join(',', @{ $data{$label} }), "\n";
    }
```

i was hoping to use this script from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/perl/threads/292981/read-and-write-multiple-file-in-a-directory) but am having great difficulty putting the 2 together:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    #If you want to open a new output file for every input file
    #Do it in your loop, not here.
    #my $outfile = "KAC.pdb";
    #open( my $fh, '>>', $outfile );
    opendir( DIR, "/data/tmp" ) or die "$!";
    my @files = readdir(DIR);
    closedir DIR;
    foreach my $file (@files) {
    open( FH, "/data/tmp/$file" ) or die "$!";
    my $outfile = "output_$file"; #Add a prefix (anything, doesn't have to say 'output')
    open(my $fh, '>', $outfile);
    while (<FH>) {
    my ($line) = $_;
    chomp($line);
    if ( $line =~ m/KAC 50/ ) {
    print $fh $_;
    }
    }
    close($fh);
    }
```

the script reads all the files in the directory and finds the line with this string 'KAC 50' and then appends that line to an `output_$file` for that `inputfile`. so there will be 1 `output_$file` for every `inputfile` that is read

issues with this script that I have noted and was looking to fix:
 - it reads the '.' and '..' files in the directory and produces a
   'output_.' and 'output_..' file
 - it will also do the same with this script file.

I was also trying to make it dynamic by getting this script to work in any directory it is run in by adding this code:

```
use Cwd qw();
my $path = Cwd::cwd();
print "$path\n";
```

and

```
opendir( DIR, $path ) or die "$!";  # open the current directory 
open( FH, "$path/$file" ) or die "$!"; #open the file
```

**EDIT::I have tried combining the versions but am getting errors.Advise greatly appreciated*

```
UserName@wabcl13 ~/Perl
$ perl formatfile_QforStackOverflow.pl
Parentheses missing around "my" list at formatfile_QforStackOverflow.pl line 13.
source dir -> /home/UserName/Perl
Can't use string ("/home/UserName/Perl/format_or"...) as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at formatfile_QforStackOverflow.pl line 28.
```

*combined code::*

```
  use strict;
    use warnings;
    use autodie;   # this is used for the multiple files part...

    #START::Getting current working directory 
    use Cwd qw();
    my $source_dir = Cwd::cwd();
    #END::Getting current working directory 

    print "source dir -> $source_dir\n";
    my $output_prefix = 'format_';

    opendir my $dh, $source_dir; #Changing this to work on current directory; changing back

    for my $file (readdir($dh)) {
        next if $file !~ /\.csv$/;
        next if $file =~ /^\Q$output_prefix\E/;

        my $orig_file = "$source_dir/$file";
        my $format_file = "$source_dir/$output_prefix$file";

        # .... old processing code here ...
        ## Start:: This part works on one file edited for this script ##
        #open my $orig_fh,   '<', 'orig.csv'   or die $!; #line 14 and 15 above already do this!!
        #open my $format_fh, '>', 'format.csv' or die $!;

        #print $format_fh scalar <$orig_fh>; # Copy header line #orig needs changeing
        print $format_file  scalar <$orig_file>; # Copy header line

        my %data;
        my @labels;

        #while (<$orig_fh>) { #orig needs changing
        while (<$orig_file>) {
          chomp;
          my @fields = split /,/, $_, -1;
          my ($label, $max_val) = @fields[1,12];
          if ( exists $data{$label} ) {
            my $prev_max_val = $data{$label}[12] || 0;
            $data{$label} = \@fields if $max_val and $max_val > $prev_max_val;
          }
          else {
            $data{$label} = \@fields;
            push @labels, $label;
          }
        }

        for my $label (@labels) {
          #print $format_fh join(',', @{ $data{$label} }), "\n";  #orig needs changing
          print $format_file join(',', @{ $data{$label} }), "\n";
        }
        ## END:: This part works on one file edited for this script ##

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan on inputting the list of files to process and their preferred output destination?  Maybe just have a fixed directory that you want to process all the cvs files, and prefix the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $source_dir = '/some/dir/with/cvs/files';
my $output_prefix = 'format_';

opendir my $dh, $source_dir;
for my $file (readdir($dh)) {
    next if $file !~ /\.csv$/;
    next if $file =~ /^\Q$output_prefix\E/;

    my $orig_file = "$source_dir/$file";
    my $format_file = "$source_dir/$output_prefix$file";

    .... old processing code here ...

}
```

Alternatively, you could just have an output directory instead of prefixing the files.  Either way, this should get you on your way.

Comment: sorry thought this was clear, i was going to just save the formated files in the same directory, but they would have a prefix to differentiate.would this be good practice? tks

Comment: It's a good enough practice as long as you code things properly.  What I've shown you will do most of that work.  You're going to need to learn some more coding skills eventually though, instead of just throwing together code provided by others on forums.  Good luck.

Comment: still getting errors, would appreciate your advice,edited my Q, tks

Comment: @HattrickNZ If you're getting syntax errors, you should focus on understanding and fixing them first.  The errors will typically tell you the exact line number that they're occurring on.  If you want help understanding a specific error message, then by all means post your code and ask a specific question.  But I'd hope to hear what you've done to try to figure out the error message yourself first.